# Expressions in control statements

Tags: syntax, programming-languages

I've never used the following kind of expressions in if statements or other control structures (example in PHP):

```
if ( ( $p = someFunction() ) !== false ) {
        // Use $p
}
```

I usually take this kind of assignment expression out and have it evaluated before I check it in an if statement.

My questions are:

- Is there a name for this technique?
- After the assignment (**$p = someFunction()**) what types can be tested for? (For example only true/false or the actual type someFuntion returns)?
- Is this reccomended and safe to use with most languages and to expect similar behaviour?

Comment: For your reference: [PHP type comparisons table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: @ladaghini wow, those are big tables to memorise ;)

Comment: Note that when using the strict equality operators (`===` and `!==`), the condition expression has to be coded carefully. As shown in the link I gave, `1 === TRUE` will evaluate to `FALSE` though 1 has a "truthy" value. `===` and `!==` don't test for "truthiness;" they test for equality within the same type. If you want to rest the truthiness of a value, try `echo !!$value`. The table of truthiness may be different for other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

You could name it using return value of assignment expression?

Why do you ask this generally? You have to check if your language supports this kind of code. Most C like languages return the value that is assigned to the variable on the left so it can be any type.